# FFMPEG CLI Language Metadata Tagging Output MP4 (Video + Audio) File

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-interface, metadata, tagging, id3

Can anyone help me understand why my attempts at tagging an audio track with language metadata using FFMPEG CLI is failing?  I've found various pieces of information on the correct syntax for the tag which I'm still not clear on (so part 1 of my question is what is the correct syntax), but even if I get it right (which I may or may not have), I am wondering if FFMPEG is failing to tag my audio track because my source is wrapped/muxed with a video essence. Does this preclude the ability to language tag?

Worth noting, attempts have been made from both MP4 and MKV sources (video and audio) to MP4 (video and audio) and M4A, MP4 and AAC audio only outputs with no success.

Also worth noting, I've also tried using the -metadata title tag with no success.

I am looking for the following metadata to show up in a mediainfo advanced mode check:

Language: en
Language: English

Here is my command line:

ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -c:v libx264 -level:v 3.0 -b:v 5000k -bufsize 4300k -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -x264opts tff=1:colorprim=bt470bg:transfer=bt470m:colormatrix=bt470bg -vf crop=720:576:0:32 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -metadata language="eng" -aspect 4:3 -y "output.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Language is a stream-level metadata parameter. To apply to all streams, use `-metadata:s language=eng`

Comment: Thanks Mulvya.  That worked perfectly.  While on the subject, maybe you can help me with my other issue which is altering stream ID's.  The playout system which requires the language metadata also requires Video to be ID: 2 and Audio to be ID: 1.  I have tried using the following tags: -streamid 1:2 -streamid 2:1 but had no success.  I've managed to alter stream ID's once in the past, but not sure why I can't now.

Comment: You can assign maps in the order you need: `-map 0:a -map 0:v`

Comment: I get the following error: Invalid input file index: 1.  It won't allow me to alter the video ID.  To be clear I am attempting to alter the metadata in a mediainfo check labeled ID, not stream identifier.

Comment: Your command only shows one input so it will be 0-based like in my comment.

Comment: I'm trying to map stream ID's, not map channels.

Comment: My additions don't map channels.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to specify exactly what ID each should be.  You're suggesting that 0 specifies the input.  How do I specify the output?

Comment: You cannot directly set ID for MP4 because there is no such attribute. What mediainfo shows as track ID is the stream/track order as per the MP4's index. The order in which ffmpeg writes streams is either 1)as per the order of input maps when these are specified or 2)the auto mapping it does when they are not. By adding `-map 0:a -map 0:v` you tell ffmpeg to first write the first input's audio and then its video.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but is a bit of a shame.  In some instances my input file might have more than 1 audio track which I would need to ignore, while still being able to map the audio track first.  From what you are saying, this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You can use `-map 0:a:0 -map 0:v` to include the first audio track first, then (all the) video tracks and skip the rest.

Comment: I see now.  Thanks.  You've been a great help!